# Is there a way to create an alias to a cmdlet in a way that it only runs if arguments are passed to the alias?

Tags: powershell, alias, wrapper

I am trying to [create an alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias?view=powershell-6) (named **which**) of the [Get-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-6) cmdlet in a way that it doesn't run if I'm not sending any arguments (because if it's run without arguments it outputs all the commands that are available).

I know this can be done using a function but I would like to keep the tab completion functionality without having to write a sizeable function that is to be placed into my [$PROFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6#the-profile-variable).

In short, I only want the alias to work if it is being passed arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do it with an [*alias*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases), because **PowerShell aliases can only refer to another command *name or path*, and can therefore neither include *arguments* nor custom logic**.
In other words: they're just *alternative names* for existing commands.

Therefore **you do need a [*function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions), but it can be a *short and simple* one**:

```bash
function which { 
  if ($args.Count) { Get-Command @args } else { Throw "Missing command name." } 
}
```

Note:

- The above uses the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) to refer to whatever arguments were passed.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842481/45375) for a solution that additionally (and optionally) supports *pipeline input*.
- While passing `-?` for showing `Get-Command`'s help does work, *tab completion* of arguments does not.

**In order to get *tab completion* as well, you'll need to write a *wrapper (proxy) function* or at least replicate `Get-Command`'s parameter declarations** - which then *does* make the function definition more complex and lengthier.

If the concern is just the size of the `$PROFILE` file itself, you can write a proxy *script* instead - `which.ps1` - which you can invoke with just `which` as well, assuming you place it in one of the directories listed in `$env:Path`<sup>[1]</sup>; see next section.

---

#### Defining a wrapper (proxy) script or function:

[Defining a wrapper (proxy) function or script](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/) is a nontrivial undertaking, but allows you to implement a robust wrapper that supports tab completion and even forwarding to the original command's help.

Note:

- **Bug alert**: As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, as of PowerShell [Core] 7.1, [`System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand.Create) neglects to include *dynamic parameters* if the target command is an (advanced) *function or script*; however, compiled *cmdlets* are *not* affected; see [GitHub issue #4792](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4792) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628204/45375) for a workaround.
- For simplicity, the following creates a wrapper *script*, `which.ps1` , and saves it in the current directory. As stated, if you place it in one of the directories listed in `$env:PATH`, you'll be able to invoke it as just `which`.
- The code below can easily be adapted to create a wrapper *function* instead: simply take the contents of the `$wrapperCmdSource` variable below and enclose it in `function which { ... }`.
- As of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5, there are some problems with the auto-generated code, which may or may not affect you; they will be fixed at some point; to learn more and to learn how to manually correct them, see [GitHub issue #10863](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10863#issuecomment-545621624).

```bash
# Create the wrapper scaffolding as source code (outputs a single [string])
$wrapperCmdSource = 
  [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Command Get-Command))
  
# Write the auto-generated source code to a script file
$wrapperCmdSource > which.ps1
```

Note:

- Even though [`System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand.Create) requires a [`System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata) instance to identify the target command, the [`System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo) instances output by `Get-Command` can be used as-is.
- Re *comment-based help*: By default, the proxy function simply *forwards* to the original cmdlet's help; however, you can optionally pass a string to serve as the comment-based help as the 2nd argument.

  - By using `[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetHelpComments()` in combination with output from `Get-Help`, you could start with a copy of the original command's help and modify it:
    `[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetHelpComments((Get-Help Get-Command))`

You now have a **fully functional `which.ps1` wrapper script that behaves like `Get-Command` itself**.

You can invoke it as follows:

```bash
./which    # Same as: Get-Command; tab completion of parameters supported.
./which -? # Shows Get-Command's help.
```

You can now **edit the script file to perform the desired customization**.

Note: The auto-generated source code contains a lot of boilerplate code; however, typically only one or two places need tweaking to implement the custom functionality.

Specifically, place the following command as the first statement inside the `begin { ... }` block:

```bash
if (-not $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput -and -not ($Name -or $CommandType -or $Module -or $FullyQualifiedModule)) {
  Throw "Missing command name or filter."
}
```

This causes the script to throw an error if the caller didn't provide *some* way of targeting a specific command or group of commands, either by direct argument or via the pipeline.

If you invoke the modified script without arguments now, you should see the desired error:

```
PS> ./which.ps1
Missing command name or filter.
...
```

---

Other **common types of customizations** are:

- Removing parameters from the wrapper, by simply removing the parameter declaration.
- Adding additional parameters to the invocation of the wrapped command, by modifying the following line in the `begin` block:

  ```bash
    # Add parameters, as needed.
    $scriptCmd = { & $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
  ```
- Preprocessing pipeline input before passing it to the wrapped command, by customizing the `process` block and replacing `$_` with your preprocessed input in the following line:

  ```bash
    # Replace $_ with a preprocessed version of it, as needed.
    $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
  ```

For an **example of a complete implementation** of a proxy function, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842481/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Caveat for *Linux* users: since the Linux file-system is case is case-*sensitive*, invocation of your script won't work case-*insensitively*, the way commands normally work in PowerShell. E.g., if your script file name is `Get-Foo.ps1`, only `Get-Foo` - using the exact same case - will work, not also `get-foo`, for instance.</sup>