# Extend cd functionality while retaining Set-Location switches

Tags: powershell, alias

I want to extend the functionality of `cd` but retain all of the existing parameters of `Set-Location`. So I created a function `go` which does a bunch of additional stuff and then aliased `cd` to it (I had to use -Option AllScope to get this to work, does anyone know why I can't just re-alias cd without using that?)

```
Set-Alias cd go -Option AllScope
```

The problem is that I would like `go` to do certain things, but to also failover to `Set-Location` functionality whenever a standard `Set-Location` switch is invoked:

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath <String> [-PassThru] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]

Set-Location [[-Path] <String>] [-PassThru] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]

Set-Location [-PassThru] [-StackName <String>] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Looking for advice in extending the functionality of a built-in Cmdlet by creating a secondary function and then re-using a built-in alias in this way? i.e. I want `cd` to continue to do all of the `Set-Location` functionality, except when new switches that I want are applied to the secondary function that it is now aliased to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MikeSh helpfully advises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60475989/45375), a proxy function (wrapper function) is the way to go:

- Create your `go` function as a proxy (wrapper) function (or script) for the `Set-Location` cmdlet, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).
- Add your custom functionality directly to this wrapper function.

`go` is then the single function that provides both `Set-Location` functionality and the desired custom functionality, so `Set-Alias cd go -Option AllScope` is sufficient.

**Important**: Since you're modifying a built-in, session-wide alias, be sure that your `go` function is a *true superset* of `Set-Location`'s functionality; that is, make sure that it neither modifies nor restricts the original behavior - otherwise, third-party code may malfunction.

---

> I had to use -Option AllScope to get this to work, does anyone know why I can't just re-alias cd without using that?

The *built in* alias `cd` is defined with `-Option AllScope`; any alias defined this way can only be modified if
`-Option AllScope` is again specified on *redefinition* with `Set-Alias`.

The reason is that `-Option AllScope` means that the alias is automatically present in *any* scope, which effectively means that the specified definition applies *session-wide*.

*Without* `-Option AllScope`, `Set-Alias` creates / modifies an alias in a *single* scope only - which is either the *current* scope by default, or the one targeted via the optional `-Scope` parameter - though all *descendant* scopes of that scope see the definition too.

This contradicts a preexisting `-Option AllScope` definition for a given alias name, so PowerShell gives you two options to resolve the contradiction:

- Modify the existing `AllScope` definition, which you must signal by specifying
  `-Option AllScope` *as part of the redefinition*, which obviously means that you're modifying the *session-wide* definition of the alias.
- *Delete* the preexisting `AllScope` definition with `Remove-Alias` (which is *not* advisable, especially with *built-in* aliases), which then allows you to create a *scope-specific* alias (by *omitting* `-Option AllScope`).

Note that if you create an alias without `-Option AllScope`, but in the *global* scope (e.g., via your `$PROFILE` file or with `-Scope Global`), the effect is *similar* to `-Option AllScope`, given that *descendant* scopes see the definition too and given that  *all* scopes are descendants of the global scope (including modules)<sup>[1]</sup>.

However, any descendant scope can *override* the global definition.

---

<sup>[1] It is technically possible to create scopes not linked to the global scope, but that option is little-known and rarely used in practice.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

its called proxy function
see [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've read through that, really useful. Marked other Mike as the answer as he linked to quite a useful example and on the `-Scope` point. Cheers.