# PowerShell, the syntax of help-function

Tags: powershell, variables, syntax

Exploring the difference between `help` and `get-help` I did:

1. `cd Function:`
2. `get-content help`
3. all the input-parameter are defined like:     `[string]${Name}`

`$`=initiate a variable, `{}` a hashtable??

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the official documentation, see the conceptual [about_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables) help topic (invoke it with `help about_Variables`), and in particular its ["Variable Names that Include Special Characters" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables#variable-names-that-include-special-characters).

**Enclosing the name of a variable in `{...}` - e.g. `${foo}` -  unambiguously *delimits the variable name* (`foo`).**

While you can use this notation with any variable reference, doing so **is *required*** in the following scenarios:

- If the **name contains unusual characters**, such as `-` or `.` (see the linked help topic for the exact set of permissible characters); e.g.:

  - `${foo-bar}`
  - `${foo.bar}`
- If the variable reference is embedded **in an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`)**, you **may need to tell PowerShell where the variable name ends**, if the immediately following characters would otherwise be interpreted as part of the variable name; e.g.:

  - `"${foo}: bar"` - without the `{...}`, PowerShell would interpret `$foo:` as an (incomplete) variable name, which fails, because `foo` is then interpreted as the name of a PS *drive* in the context of [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375).

    - Note: An alternative in this case is to `` ` ``-escape the `:` character: `` "$foo`: bar" ``
  - `"A ${foo}l and his money ..."` - without the `{...}`, PowerShell would look for variable `$fool` instead.

While in your example (`${Name}`) enclosing in `{...}` is *not* necessary, the reason that it is used is that the code was *automatically generated* as a [proxy function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375) that wraps the `Get-Help` cmdlet, and this generation mechanism methodically encloses all variables in `{...}`.