# PowerShell Script SCP command

Tags: powershell, scp

I have following script,

```
$servers = "server1","server2"
ForEach($Server In $servers){
    scp.exe -r 'username@'+$Server+':/home/copylogs/logs' .\logs_prod'
}
```

but server variable is not working as aspected, any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass an *expression* as an argument - a string concatenation operation with `+` in your case - you must include it in `(...)`

```
scp.exe -r ('username@'+$Server+':/home/copylogs/logs') .\logs_prod
```

Alternatively, you could use an [*expandable string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (string interpolation), `"..."`:

```
scp.exe -r "username@${Server}:/home/copylogs/logs" .\logs_prod
```

<sup>Note the need to enclose the variable name, `Server` in `{...}` in this case, so that the `:` that follows isn't interpreted as part of the variable name - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61206641/45375).</sup>

Comment: How do you provide password also with this? I know we should do it with ssh keys but if we want to use password how to do that?

Comment: @Stack_IQ Sounds like you need an external utility for that, `sshpass`: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955428/45375).