# How to set an env var containing a special character in powershell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, environment-variables

In python, it's valid to have env vars that have "|" in them. but in powershell, its not possible to set these. eg:

```
$env:OVERRIDEPARM_|out|serverworkdir = "something"
```

Produces this error:

```
out: The term 'out' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Would I use a function instead to do that somehow?  Or is there another way?
Note: I'm not talking about system env vars.

I recognise this question below is similar, but doesn't ask the same thing since I'm not talking about the help function, and it doesn't come up in search, so my question will help other searching for this specific problem - [PowerShell, the syntax of help-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205427/powershell-the-syntax-of-help-function)

Comment: Use `${ }`, `${env:OVERRIDEPARM_|out|serverworkdir} = ...`

Comment: Alternatively use `Set-Item 'env:OVERRIDEPARM_|out|serverworkdir' -Value 'something'`

Comment: The linked post is not an exact duplicate, but it explains the `{...}` syntax for enclosing variable names that contain special characters.