# Powershell: What's the difference between Alias and Function?

Tags: windows, function, powershell, scripting, alias

Im setting up my powershell profile to create aliases of commonly used commands. [On Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7#examples) it says, if I want to make an alias for a command with parameters, I should make the value of the alias a Function that does that.[image]. However, when I type the name of the function in the command line it works just as well as an alias.

In other words, in the above picture, if I typed `CD32` it would behave the same as if I typed `Go` in the command line

So my question is: Why do I use aliases pointing to functions when I could just have a function? Are there feature differences between the two?

Comment: What that documentation is saying is that if you want to create an "alias" for a command and specify parameter values as part of the "alias", you must use a function. You can certainly create an alias for a command that takes parameters, and you can specify those parameters when using the alias, but you cannot fix any of the parameters in place for the alias. The alias is just an alias for the command, not for command-with-specific-values. For that you need to use a function.

Comment: Let me rephrase. The `CD32` function above, since it wants to pass the parameter `C:\Windows\System32` to `Set-Location`, a function has to be made. If you simply want to make an alias for `Set-Location` you can use an alias, but then it will function exactly like `Set-Location`, and so when you use the alias you also has to tell it which location to set. Does any of this makes sense ?

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. So an alias acts just like the command it is pointing to, including how you give it parameters. It's kind of a shorthand of writing a command.

Comment: Exactly. That was ... quite a bit clearer than what I wrote :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- An [***alias***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) in PowerShell allows you to define ***an alternative name* for another command**.

  - Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, **you *cannot include pass-through arguments* in its definition - you need a *function* for that** (see below).
  - The **typical use case is to define a *short* alternative name for *convenience of interactive invocation***; for instance, PowerShell has a built in `gc` alias for its `Get-Content` cmdlet. PowerShell even recommends a naming convention for aliases, based on official short alias prefixes for its [approved verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands), such as the `g` for the `Get` verb in the given example.
  - Another, *problematic* use is to define aliases named for a *different shell's* commands; for instance, PowerShell has a built in `dir` alias for its `Get-ChildItem`, named for `cmd.exe`'s (Command Prompt's) internal `dir` command. While that may be somewhat helpful while transitioning from `cmd.exe`, it only works in very simple invocations, and quickly becomes problematic due to PowerShell's fundamentally different command-line syntax and differing parameter names.
  - Another, *unproblematic* use is to define an alias for an external executable whose directory isn't listed in the path (`$env:PATH`); e.g., if you want to execute `c:\path\to\foo.exe` as just `foo` without having to add  `c:\path\to` to `$env:PATH`, you can use `Set-Alias foo c:\path\to\foo.exe`.
  - Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, aliases *are* (invariably) usable in *scripts* (`*.ps1` files), but their use in scripts is *discouraged* in the interest of robustness and long-term stability.
- A [***function***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions), as is to be expected, is a **named unit of code that can accept arguments and can perform arbitrary operations**.

  - **A function is what you need to use if you want to *wrap* existing commands**, by hard-coding pass-through arguments and / or providing custom logic around the invocation of the wrapped command - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).

---

As for **whether it makes sense to *define an alias for a function***, if implementation of your command requires a function (due to requiring more than just a simple name mapping):

- If all you need is *one* (short) name for your command, you can define your function *directly* with that name - no alias needed.
- By contrast, if your function needs a *long* name, especially an [advanced (cmdlet-like) function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) that adheres to PowerShell's verb-noun naming convention (e.g., `Invoke-Foo`), and you also want a *short* name for interactive convenience (e.g., `foo`), you'll have to also define an alias for that function with that short name (e.g., `Set-Alias foo Invoke-Foo`).

Comment: an `alias`  works with parameters in one occasion: `set-alias a get-alias`, then `a foo` will work if you have `set-alias foo hi`. result: `hi(story)` because `hi` is a ps alias.

Comment: I don't understand your example, @Timo. Obviously you can pass parameters (arguments) _to already defined aliases_ on _invocation_, and aliases can even refer to other aliases, but the point is that you cannot "bake" predefined arguments into an alias _definition_, because an alias is simply another name for another _command_, and not for a command _plus predefined arguments_.

Comment: Ok, there is no alias body in contrast to function body.