# Make alias in powershell to run the command that may include further parameters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a alias in powershell that uses name of the parameter and a file in different directory, in alias I can set the `python c:\sqlmap\sqlmap.py` but when I use the alias it just prints out the sqlmap first page instead of using the further parameters that sqlmap need to use

```
Set-Alias -Name sqlmap -Value 'python  D:\tools\sqlmap-master\sqlmap.py'
```

or I tried the functional loop also

```
function sqlmap { 
    $current_dir = (get-lcoation).location
    set-location 'D:\tools\sqlmap-master\'
    python sqlmap.py
    if ($?){
        set-location current_dir
    }
}
```

but none of them taking the arguments like sqlmap basic parameter is `python sqlmap -u https:/web.com..... --dbs`

how can I make this alias to let sqlmap independently... i want to reduce the use of going into directory and then running `python sqlmap.py ...... everytime`

Comment: As for attempting to use an _alias_: Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, you _cannot include pass-through arguments_ in a PowerShell alias definition - you need a _function_ for that, as shown in the accepted answer. PowerShell aliases are simply _alternative names_ for other commands, with no ability to "bake in" arguments; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292585/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the arguments provided, [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) the `$args` automatic variable when invoking python:

```
function sqlmap {
  python D:\tools\sqlmap-master\sqlmap.py @args
}
```