# Powershell functions do not work with spaces

Tags: windows, powershell, function, terminal, alias

I am trying to set up an alias in Powershell. For some weird reason, they do not support spaces (arguments), so I have to create a function instead

I ran this command:

`function glo { git log --oneline }`

I expected that afterwards I could run this using `glo`.
But running `glo` results in
`glo : The term 'git log --oneline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again`
instead of running `git log --oneline`

How to set up this alias? Why is it difficult to set up aliases in Powershell compared to Linux where this is easy with the `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Function as presented should work fine. Either show what you are actually running or provide more details. Which powershell version? Did you get some funny characters that PS does not treat as whitespace between the command and arguments?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: The **function definition in your question is technically correct**, but the error message suggests you used a *different* function definition - see the bottom section. The first section contains *general* information.</sup>

- Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, you ***cannot include pass-through arguments* in a PowerShell [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) definition - you indeed need a [*function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) for that**.

  - Use the **[automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args)** to **relay all arguments** passed to a function to its target command line (if needed).
- **PowerShell aliases** - by design - **are simply *alternative names*** for other commands, with ***no* ability to "bake in" arguments** - for more information about aliases vs. function in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292585/45375).

Therefore:

```bash
# Defines a 'glo' command that executes `git log --oneline` with 
# additional arguments, if any, passed through.
function glo { git log --oneline @args }
```

- Note the use of `@args` rather than `$args`, which is an instance of parameter [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting), which with an *array* variable passes the array's elements *as individual arguments* to the target command.

  - Since you're calling an *external program* (`git`), this isn't strictly necessary, because `$args` would do that too; if the target command were a *PowerShell* command, however, only `@args` would pass all arguments through individually.
  - Note:

    - The function also works if you pass *no* arguments, in which case `git log --oneline` is executed.
    - More effort is needed **if your function also needs to support *pipeline input*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842481/45375) for an example.
- For a **more sophisticated way of wrapping commands**, using ***proxy functions***, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).
- To **make such "aliases" (wrapper functions) available in all future sessions**, add them to your **[`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)** file.

---

As for **what you tried**:

The function definition in your question - `function glo { git log --oneline }` - is actually correct, assuming you don't need support for additional, ad hoc pass-through arguments when calling `glo`.

However, the error message you're showing implies that you instead defined your function as follows:

```bash
# !! BROKEN
function glo { & 'git log --oneline' }
```

This cannot be expected to work, because `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), expects a *command name or executable path only* as its first argument - any *arguments* must be passed separately.

If you wanted to use `&` in the function definition - which isn't necessary, given that command name `git` neither has spaces nor is expressed in terms of *variables* - define the function body as:
`& git log --oneline`

Comment: This does not change anything, it still tries to call the command "git log --oneline" as if it was one command. Furthermore relaying the arguments to the command the function calls is not the issue here nor needed.

Comment: @Riikka, it's fine if you don't need to relay arguments - it'll work either way. Paste the function definition ass shown into an interactive PowerShell session and then run `glo`

Comment: @Riikka, it was previously in a comment, but I've moved the explanation of what   the problem with your _actual_ function definition was, as implied by the error message, into a new section of the answer. (The function definition you're _showing_ is actually correct, if you don't need pass-through arguments.)