# Alias a command in Windows Terminal using Powershell as the default profile

Tags: powershell, alias, tmux, windows-terminal, fzf

I want to alias the following 2 commands (combining ssh with fuzzy finder) in the Windows Terminal which uses the default profile as PowerShell:

fzf_ssh: `ssh $(cat .ssh_known_hosts | fzf)`
fzf_ssh_tmux: `ssh $(cat .ssh_known_hosts | fzf) -t tmux a`

(The file .ssh_known_hosts is a file I created with the username@hostname entries)

---

I found the following article, but they are aliasing it for cmd: [save-your-precious-dev-time-with-command-aliases-in-windows-terminal](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/save-your-precious-dev-time-with-command-aliases-in-windows-terminal/).

---

The following post suggests updating the $profile file of PowerShell with Set-Alias: [windows_terminal_how_do_you_set_aliass](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/nl6b36/windows_terminal_how_do_you_set_aliass/)
I made the following entry in the $profile file:

```
Set-Alias -Name fzf_ssh -Value ssh $(cat .ssh_known_hosts | fzf)
Set-Alias -Name fzf_ssh_tmux -Value ssh $(cat .ssh_known_hosts | fzf) -t tmux a
```

But on launching a new Windows Terminal session, the commands get executed and open the fuzzy finder which is not what I want. I just want it to alias those 2 commands.

---

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you need a sudo alias.  See : https://blog.nullmode.com/blog/2014/06/28/getting-personal-with-powershell/

Comment: How will a sudo alias help here? I am not facing any permission issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define [*functions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) rather than [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases), because in PowerShell an alias is simply *another name* for a command, and therefore doesn't support passing *arguments*:

```bash
function fzf_ssh      { ssh (cat .ssh_known_hosts | fzf) }
function fzf_ssh_tmux { ssh (cat .ssh_known_hosts | fzf) -t tmux a }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292585/45375) for background information.

---

As for *what you tried*:

- Since an alias is just another name for a command, the `-Value` parameter of [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias) accepts just *one* argument, namely the name of the command for which to create the alias.
- The command enclosed in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), is executed *instantly*  (as an aside: `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), as used above, is usually sufficient).

  - Use of `$(...)`, `(...)` and `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), when used *outside of a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)* (`{ ... }`) *always* execute *right away*.
- Thereafter, your attempt to (positionally) pass *additional* arguments (`$(...)`) to `Set-Alias` ultimately causes a *syntax error* (`A positional parameter cannot be found ...`).