# What is the simplest way to make Alias in powershell?

Tags: powershell, terminal, windows-10

I was wondering if there's any simple way to make aliases for powershell like cmd.
For example: In cmd, `doskey art=php artisan $*` where `$*` is optional. Currently, I'm using the following alias in powershell.

```
function runArtisanCommand
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position = 0, ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
        $command
    )
    php artisan $command
}

Set-Alias art runArtisanCommand
```

This works somewhat but don't take flags. For example: I can't write `art -h` or `art route:list -c`. In `art -h` command, it prints the output of `php artisan` and don't read flag at all but in `art route:list -c` command, it errors out with.

```
runArtisanCommand : Missing an argument for parameter 'command'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object' and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ art route:list -c
+                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [runArtisanCommand], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,runArtisanCommand
```

I would love a simpler solution than this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `function runArtisanCommand {& php artisan $args}`

Comment: As a follow on to what Mathias gives you. You are trying to set an alias to your function name, that's not a thing. You can set alias directly in your function. Of course and alias is a short name for your full function name. function Verb-Noun { [CmdletBinding()] [Alias('vn')] Param ( )}. You don't need an alias if you are just going to call/run your function by your function name as Mathias is showing you. For running executables, see options here:: [• PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

Comment: @postanote: Good point re verb-noun naming convention if you want your function to have a longer name, separate from a short alias. But there's nothing wrong per se with using `Set-Alias` to define the alias - in fact, if you're not the author of the target function, you have no other choice. Also, when you author a module, you may want to keep your alias definitions separate from the function definitions for maintainability.

Comment: @postanote While I appreciate you pointing out an issue in my code and adding info that I didn't knew before i:e "[Alias('xx')]", I think phrases like "that's not a thing" shouldn't be used unless the code causes either an error or notable performance difference. Phrases like this could be discouraging for beginners. I believe in "make it work first, follow best practices later". P.S: This is a suggestion and not a criticism. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **simplest and most convenient way to pass unknown arguments through is by [spatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)
the [automatic `$args` array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) - as `@args` - in a *simple* function or script** (one that neither uses a `[CmdletBinding()]` nor `[Parameter()]` attributes):

```sh
# Note: @args rather than $args makes the function work with named 
#       arguments for PowerShell commands too - see explanation below.
function runArtisanCommand { php artisan @args } 

# As in your question: Define alias 'art' for the function
# Note: Of course, you could directly name your *function* 'art'.
#       If you do want the function to have a longer name, consider one
#       that adheres to PowerShell's Verb-Noun naming convention, such as
#       'Invoke-ArtisanCommand'.
Set-Alias art runArtisanCommand
```

<sup>As an aside: Since the target executable, `php`, is neither *quoted* nor specified based on a *variable or expression*, it can be invoked as-is; otherwise, you would need `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for background information.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

The problem was that use of `-c` as a *pass-through* argument only works if you precede it with `--`:

```sh
# OK, thanks to '--'
art -- route:list -c
```

`--` tells PowerShell to treat all remaining arguments as *unnamed* (positional) arguments, instead of trying to interpret tokens such as `-c` as *parameter names*.

**Without `--`, `-c` is interpreted as referring to your `-command` parameter** (the parameter you declared as `$command` with `ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true`), given that PowerShell allows you to specify name *prefixes* in lieu of full parameter names, as long as the given prefix is unambiguous.

Because a parameter of any type other than `[switch]` requires an associated argument, `-c` (aka `-command`) failed with an error message to that effect.

**You could have avoided the collision by naming your parameter so that it doesn't collide with any pass-through parameters**, such as by naming it `-_args` (with parameter variable `$_args`):

```
function runArtisanCommand
{
    param(
        # Note: `Mandatory = $false` and `Position = 0` are *implied*.
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        $_args
    )
    php artisan @_args
}
```

However, given that **use of a `[Parameter()]` attribute implicitly makes your function an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) function**, it **invariably also accepts [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters), such as `-ErrorAction`, `-OutVariable`, `-Verbose`...** - all of which can be passed by unambiguous prefix / short alias too; e.g., `-outv` for `-OutVariable`, or alias `-ea` for `ErrorAction`; **collisions with them cannot be avoided**.

Therefore, intended pass-through arguments such as `-e` *still* wouldn't work:

```sh
# FAILS, because -e ambiguously matches common parameters -ErrorAction 
# and -ErrorVariable.
PS> art router:list -e
Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'e' is ambiguous.
Possible matches include: -ErrorAction -ErrorVariable.
```

Again, `--` is needed:

```sh
# OK, thanks to '--'
art -- router:list -e
```

---

**Summary**:

- Especially for **functions wrapping calls to *external programs***, such as `php.exe`, using a *simple* function with `@args`, as shown at the top, is not only simpler, but also more robust.
- For **functions wrapping *PowerShell commands*** (with explicitly declared parameters):

  - a *simple* function with `@args` works too,
  - but if you also want **support for tab-completion** and **showing a [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax)** with the supported parameters, by passing `-?`, or via [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help), consider defining an (invariably *advanced*) ***proxy (wrapper) function* via the PowerShell SDK** - see below.

---

**Optional background information: Pass-through arguments in PowerShell**

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, **the simplest way to pass (undeclared) arguments passed to a function or script *through* to another command is to use the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args)**, which is an automatically populated array of all the arguments passed to a *simple* function or script (one that isn't [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced), through use of the `[CmdletBinding()]` and/or `[Parameter()]` attributes).

As for **why `@args` (splatting) rather than `$args` should be used**:

- Using `$args` as-is in your wrapper function only works for passing *positional* arguments through (those not prefixed by the parameter name; e.g., `*.txt`), as opposed to *named* arguments (e.g., `-Path *.txt`).
- If the ultimate target command is an *external program* (such as `php.exe` in this case), this isn't a problem, because PowerShell of necessity then treats *all* arguments as positional arguments (it cannot know the target program's syntax).
- However, if a *PowerShell* command (with formally declared parameters) is ultimately called, only [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) the `$args` array - which syntactically means us of `@args` instead - supports passing *named* arguments through.<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore, as a matter of habit, **I suggest always using `@args` in simple wrapper functions**, which equally works with external programs.<sup>[2]</sup>

To give an example with a simple wrapper function for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem):

```
# Simple wrapper function for Get-ChildItem that lists recursively
# and by relative path only.
function dirTree {
  # Use @args to make sure that named arguments are properly passed through.
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name @args 
}

# Invoke it with a *named* argument passed through to Get-ChildItem
# If $args rather than @args were used inside the function, this call would fail.
dirTree -Filter *.txt
```

**Using a *proxy function* for more sophisticated pass-through processing:**

The use of **`@args` is convenient, but comes at the expense of *not* supporting the following**:

- **tab-completion**, given that tab-completion only works with formally declared parameters (typically with a `param(...)` block).
- **showing a [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax)** with the supported parameters, by passing `-?`, or via [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help)

To **overcome these limitations**, the **parameter declarations of the ultimate target command must be *duplicated*** in the (then advanced) wrapper function; while that is cumbersome, **PowerShell can automate the process by scaffolding a so-called *proxy (wrapper) function* via the PowerShell SDK** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).

Note:

- With respect to *common* parameters such as `-ErrorAction`, it is the proxy function itself that (automatically) processes them, but that shouldn't make a difference to the caller.
- Scaffolding a proxy function only works with *PowerShell commands*, given that PowerShell has no knowledge of the syntax of external programs.

  - However, you can *manually* duplicate the parameter declarations of the external target program.

---

<sup>[1] Note that the automatic `$args` array has built-in magic to support this; passing named arguments through with splatting is *not* supported with a custom *array* and requires use of a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) instead, as discussed in the help topic about splatting linked to above.</sup>

<sup>[2] In fact, only `@args` also supports the correct interpretation of `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. @Mathias comment solved my problem but then I switched to your solution and don't see an immediate difference but all the explaination helps. Marking your answer as accepted because can't mark Mathias comment as best and your's will solve the problem too. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks, @Jerry555555. When wrapping external programs, `$args` instead of `@args` works fine, except if you need to use `--%`. When wrapping PowerShell commands, only `@args` works properly. Therefore, the answer recommends `@args` as the best overall solution.