# make new-alias run a specific python file

Tags: python, powershell, alias

I have a python program that creates a numbered list up to the value i enter
I have tried using `new-alias numberlist "python C:\path\to\file\numberlist.py"` to do this but it returns the error
`numberlist : The term 'python C:\path\to\file\numberlist.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`
Does anyone know what I can do to make this work on PowerShell?

Comment: Do you mean this `alias new="python C:\path\to\file\numberlist.py"`?

Comment: No. I would like the name to be numberlist still. and new-alias is what i have used to create a new alias

Comment: In short: Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, you _cannot include pass-through arguments_ in a PowerShell alias definition - you need a _function_ for that. PowerShell aliases are simply _alternative names_ for other commands, with no ability to "bake in" arguments - see the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55539278/45375). Therefore: `function numberlist { python C:\path\to\file\numberlist.py @args }`

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Mathias.

Comment: @mklement0, this should've been an answer. It just saves my day.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MrCrHaM, but answers already exist: please see the linked duplicates.