# Powershell's equivalent to Linux's: ls -al

Tags: linux, powershell, ls

I don't use Powershell nor Linux very often so I am unsure of what: ls -al would be in Powershell "terms". I tried to find something but it said there wasn't an equivalent command in Powershell. Seems odd so I figured I would ask quick.

Comment: A strict equivalent might not exist. Since Linux and Windows are different operating systems

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, indeed there is no _strict_ equivalent, but given that [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) runs on Linux (and macOS) too, this isn't so much about different platforms, I presume, but about a _Powershell-idiomatic way_ of getting _analogous_ functionality  (and on macOS and Linux you can just call `ls -al` directly).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ls` Unix utility's options you're using:

- `-a` option includes *hidden* items, which on Unix-like platforms are file-system items whose name starts with `.`
- `-l` requests the so-called *long format*, which produces tabular output that includes the file-system items' mode, user and group ownership, the last-write timestamp, the item size, and its name.

The **PowerShell equivalent** is:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Force
```

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s `-Force` switch includes *hidden* items in the output - although, unlike with `ls`, the `.` and `..` entries representing the target directory itself and its parent directory are *not* included (which makes it the equivalent of the more useful `-A` `ls` option).
- The equivalent of *long format* formatting is used *by default*; if, conversely, you're interested in file names (relative paths) *only*, use the `-Name` switch.
- Note: By default, `Get-ChildItem` targets the *current* location (directory); to specify an input path explicitly, use either the `-Path` parameter - for wildcard patterns - or the `-LiteralPath` parameter - for literal (verbatim) paths. The first *positional* argument (one not prefixed by a parameter names) implicitly binds to `-Path`; e.g., the following command targets the current user's home directory:

  ```bash
  Get-ChildItem -Force -LiteralPath $HOME
  ```

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72495988/45375) for more information.

See the bottom section for **shortening this command** and **defining a convenience "alias" (function)**.

---

There's one ***fundamental* difference** between `ls` and `Get-ChildItem`, however:

- `ls` outputs *formatted text*, and for that reason parsing its output is generally discouraged.
- In PowerShell, *formatting* is separated from *data* and it is *objects*, not *strings* that are output.

  - That is, irrespective of the rich *display formatting* that `Get-ChildItem` output presents in the terminal, its actual output are *objects* of type [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo), which can safely be used for further *programmatic processing* if captured in a variable, sent to other PowerShell comments through a [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines), or used in an expression.
- For instance, expression `(Get-ChildItem -Force).FullName` outputs the *full paths* of all items in the current directory.

---

**For *interactive* convenience** (you shouldn't do that in scripts), you can use ***built-in aliases*** and ***unambiguous parameter-name prefixes*** to **shorten the command**:

```bash
gci -fo
```

`gci` is built-in alias for `Get-ChildItem`, and its name follows PowerShell's naming conventions, where each so-called [approved verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) also has an approved 1-2 letter *alias* form; running `Get-Verb Get` reveals that the approved `Get` verb's alias form is `g`; while the *noun* part isn't formally regulated, remembering that `ci` stands for `ChildItem` should be easy.

`-fo` is the shortest parameter-name prefix that unambiguously refers to the `-Force` switch (just `-f` alone could also refer to `-Filter`<sup>[1]</sup>)

- Note: Some parameters themselves have actual *aliases*, such as `-h` for `-Hidden` or `-ad` for `-Directory`, but `-Force` does not.
- Unlike unambiguous parameter-name prefixes, which can become ambiguous over time if new parameters are added to a command, parameter aliases are safe to use in scripts, although for readability the full names are preferable.

To see *all* aliases defined for a given command (`Get-ChildItem` in this example):

```bash
PS> Get-Alias -Definition Get-ChildItem

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           dir -> Get-ChildItem                                          
Alias           gci -> Get-ChildItem
```

<sup>To limit output to *built-in* aliases, i.e. to exclude aliases defined by other modules or `$PROFILE` scripts, run `pwsh -noprofile { Get-Alias -Definition Get-ChildItem }` (in Windows PowerShell, use `powershell` instead of `pwsh`.</sup>

- The above shows the output on *macOS and Linux*.
- **On *Windows* you will see that `ls` is *another* built-in alias**.

  - This is a ***legacy* alias** from the time PowerShell was a Windows-only shell, and is **best avoided**:

    - In general, [aliases take precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Precedence) over external programs with the same name, and it isn't a good idea to *shadow* (override) a platform's standard command-line utilities; while that doesn't apply to alias `ls` on Windows, it does in other cases, namely `where` (shadows `where.exe`) and `sc` (Windows PowerShell-only, shadows `sc.exe`)
    - Specifically, given that the real `ls` Unix utility and `Get-ChildItem` have such vastly different syntax (and behavior), exposing the latter as `ls` is likely to cause confusion.

Therefore, **it is advisable to stick to those aliases that are abbreviated forms of the *PowerShell* command names, such as `gci` for `Get-ChildItem`, and `gc` for `Get-Content`**. While that doesn't initially help with transitioning from familiar names such as `ls` / `dir` and `cat`, the fact that PowerShell cmdlet names as well as their abbreviated aliases are systematic and convention-based makes it easier to memorize them going forward.

**Defining a convenience "alias" with *preset arguments*, using a `function`**:

POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` allow you to define aliases with *preset* arguments, such as `alias ll='ls -al'`

By contrast, [aliases in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) are mere *name mappings* and you need to declare a *function* instead (which you can add to your `$PROFILE` file for availability in future session):

```bash
# Equivalent of bash alias `alias ll='ls -al'`
function ll { ls -al @args }
```

Or, an analogous `gcih` function (`h` denoting *hidden*) based on `Get-ChildItem`:

```bash
function gcih { Get-ChildItem -Force @args }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375) for more information about aliases vs. functions in PowerShell, including how to create more sophisticated wrapper functions.

---

<sup>[1] *Conceptually*, it could also refer to the `-File` parameter, but *technically* the latter is a *dynamic* parameter, specific to PowerShell's file-system provider, and is therefore not being considered during the ambiguity check.</sup>