# Git "ls -a " command is not working in VSCode

Tags: powershell

i was trying to know the list of everything in my Repo.

```
PS E:\Git & Github\Lerning-Github> ls -a
Get-ChildItem : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'a' is ambiguous. Possible matches 
include: -Attributes -Directory -File -Hidden -ReadOnly -System.
At line:1 char:4
+ ls -a
+    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: You are using `Windows PowerShell`. `ls -a` is not a PowerShell command. You can config to use `git-bash` as the VSCode terminal.

Comment: For the record, `ls` is a Unix command, not a "Git command".

Answer (score 0):

A similar question to yours

[Powershell's equivalent to Linux's: ls -al](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66269685/powershells-equivalent-to-linuxs-ls-al)

if you want to use the **ls -a** command install [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads), depending on your OS, if you use Windows [download the .exe](https://git-scm.com/download/win) file from this page and follow the installation procedure.

Comment: Duplicate questions should simply be close voted, not answered with a duplicate answer.