# Powershell Set-Alias for long command

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell alias for my ng build command which is fairly long.

`node --max_old_space_size=4096 .\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng build --configuration=debug --watch`

Aliasing the command directly using `Set-Alias -Name ngBuild -Value node --max_old_space_size=4096 .\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng build --configuration=debug --watch` doesn't work for me.

Comment: `Set-Alias` is meant for cmdlets / functions, not to store `scriptblocks`. I guess, an option you have is to store your command inside a function with that name you wanted.

Comment: You can make a function with the command, and even make an alias for that command.

Comment: @Santago ALWAYS seconds ahead of me haha

Comment: In short: Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, you _cannot include pass-through arguments_ in a PowerShell alias definition - you need a _function_ for that. PowerShell aliases are simply _alternative names_ for other commands, with no ability to "bake in" arguments. E.g., to define a short command `bar` that invokes command `foo` with fixed argument `bar` while passing all other arguments through, use `function bar { foo bar @args }`  - see the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375) for more information.