# Powershell: Forward arguments and pipeline input to alias function

Tags: powershell

How do I forward all pipeline input and arguments to a command inside an alias function.

For example if I wanted to alias tail

```
function tail {
  coreutils tail @args
}
```

works fine with `tail -n 5 test.txt`

but not with `cat test.txt | tail -n 5`

even though `cat test.txt | coreutils tail -n 5` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest case, use the following:

```bash
function tail {
  if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { # Pipeline input present.
    # $Input passes the collected pipeline input through.
    $Input | coreutils tail @args
  } else {
    coreutils tail @args
  }
}
```

The down-side of this approach is that **all pipeline input is collected in memory first**, before it is relayed to the target program.

---

**A *streaming* solution** - where input objects (lines) - are passed through *as they become available* - requires more effort:

```bash
function tail {
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
  param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
      $InputObject
      ,
      [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
      [string[]] $PassThruArgs
  )
  
  begin
  {
    # Set up a steppable pipeline.
    $scriptCmd = { coreutils tail $PassThruArgs }  
    $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
    $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
  }
  
  process
  {
    # Pass the current pipeline input through.
    $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
  }
  
  end
  {
    $steppablePipeline.End()
  }
  
}
```

The above [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) is a **so-called *proxy function***, explained in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).