# Adding Arguments to PowerShell Alias Functions

Tags: powershell, grep

I just installed `grep` on PowerShell through `chocolatey` and using it, I could search for a string I want from any text as shown below:

[image]

However, I don't want to always have to type `grep --color`, hence I tried to make an alias on my `$profile` like this:

```
Function grep($a1){
  grep --color $a1
}
```

but then I would get an error:

[image]

So I tried:

```
Set-Alias grep "grep --color"
```

but then I get yet another error:

[image]

I can't think of anything else to make this work, hence I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: That's because, *grep.exe* doesn't understand what you're telling it to work off since you're only passing it a value. You can use the [automatic variable of `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input) to pass over your pipeline input into *grep.exe*, and your argument. So, something like: `function grap ($text) { $input | grep --color $text}`. As for your alias, PowerShell is very literal when it comes to the `Set-Alias` cmdlet so you're basically telling it just be a string.

Comment: Good point, @Abraham, though in this case the infinite recursion to due to also naming the function `grep` is the primary problem. Also, `$input` must be only be used if actual pipeline input is present (`$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput`), so as to also enable calls where input is alternatively provided via _file paths_ passed as _arguments_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Aliases* in PowerShell are mere alternative *names* for other commands, so you cannot use them to include *arguments* to pass to these other commands.

You therefore indeed need a *function*, but since you're naming it the same as the external program you're wrapping, you need to disambiguate so as to avoid an infinite recursion:

```
function grep {
  $externalGrep = Get-Command -Type Application grep
  if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { # pipeline (stdin) input present
    # $args passes all arguments through.
    $input | & $externalGrep --color $args
  } else {
    & $externalGrep --color $args
  }
}
```

Note:

- Use of the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) to relay pipeline (stdin) input means that this input is *collected (buffered) in full first*. More effort is needed to implement a true *streaming* solution - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842481/45375) for an example.

Alternatively - at least on Unix-like platforms - you can set an *environment* variable to control `grep`'s coloring behavior, which may obviate the need for a function wrapper; the equivalent of the `--color` parameter is to set `$env:GREP_COLOR='always'` (the other supported values are `'never'` and `'auto'`).