# Use Two Different Alias in SameSession on PS like Linux

Tags: powershell

In linux environment we can disable alias and call original command with ".\ls", is it possible also powershell?

```
function Get-WmiObject { 
    # In here How Can I Use original "Get-WmiObject" command?
    Get-WmiObject "win32_bios" | select Manufacturer
}
New-Alias -Name "Get-WmiObject" -Value Get-WmiObject -Force
```

- Current session when I type "Get-WmiObject", it will be return me
  Get-WmiObject "win32_bios" | select Manufacturer
- But first of all, it has to run **"Get-WmiObject"** original command inside my function

**Error**

```
Get-WmiObject : The term 'Get-WmiObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-WmiObject:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: wouldnt it be simpler to name your function `Get-Manufacturer` ? then you would be able to keep using `Get-WmiObject` in the same session if needed? in any case you can use `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-WmiObject` inside the function and no `New-Alias`

Comment: Simple.  Create a function with alias name that has one instruction that call the original function.

Comment: Microsoft.PowerShell.Management ... solved my problem thank u @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In linux environment we can disable alias and call original command with ".\ls"

I think you meant `\ls`, which would bypass an *alias* named `ls` in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash; however, it would *not* bypass a *function* of the same name.

To bypass *both* functions and aliases, you need to *selectively* use:

- the `builtin` builtin for shadowed *builtins* (built-in commands), such as `cd` (e.g., `builtin cd`)
- `which` for *external utilities*, such as `ls` (e.g, `"$(which ls)" -l`)

---

In *PowerShell*, by contrast, you can use the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet with its `-Type` (`-CommandType`) parameter to obtain the command form of interest, and invoke the result with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

- Obtaining a specific command form this way and invoking it *bypasses* the precedence of command forms that applies when invoking commands *by name*, as detailed in the conceptual [about_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Precedence) help topic
- Thus, using `Get-Command -Type` is a *single* mechanism that allows you to invoke the desired form of any command, and therefore works equally with *cmdlets* (`-Type Cmdlet`) and *external programs* (`-Type Application`), for instance.

Applied to your case:

```bash
function Get-WmiObject { 
  & (Get-Command -Type Cmdlet Get-WmiObject) "win32_bios" | 
    Select-Object Manufacturer
}
```

Note:

- You do *not* also have to define an *alias* in addition to your custom `Get-WmiObject` *function* - the latter is enough.

  - In fact, trying to define an alias with the same name as an existing command not only doesn't make any sense, it shouldn't even be *allowed* - yet as of PowerShell 7.3.6 such a definition is accepted and then fails *on invocation*, as you've experienced - see [GitHub issue #20153](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20153).
- In the case of invoking *cmdlets* and *module-originated functions*, specifically, you can alternatively - and less unambiguously<sup>[1]</sup> - use a *module-qualified command name*, as [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggests: that is, you can qualify the cmdlet/function name with the name of its originating module, by placing the module name before the command name, separate with `\`; e.g.:

  ```bash
   Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-WmiObject
  ```

  - To discover which module a given cmdlet or function (if any) originates from, you can again use `Get-Command`:

    ```bash
    # -> 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'
    (Get-Command -Type Cmdlet Get-WmiObject).Module.Name
    ```
- As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the **WMI cmdlets should be avoided**, not least because **[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, where all future effort will go, **doesn't even *have* them anymore**.<sup>[2]</sup> Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Although atypical, it is possible for *multiple* versions of a given module to be have been loaded *side by side*. To distinguish between those versions, you need to know the *specific module version* whose command you're trying to invoke, which requires using `Get-Command`'s `-FullyQualifiedModule` parameter. You can find the module names and versions of *all* forms of a command with a given name with, e.g.  `Get-Command Get-WmiObject -All | Select Module, Version`. Once you know the desired version number, use something like:

`& (Get-Command -FullyQualifiedModule @{ ModuleName = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'; RequiredVersion = '3.1.0.0' } Get-WmiObject) -?`</sup>

<sup>[2] The WMI cmdlets can now be *called*, namely via a hidden *Windows PowerShell* process used by the [Windows PowerShell Compatibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility), but that is best avoided, as you both pay a performance penalty and lose type fidelity, which notably includes loss of the *methods* of WMI objects. (Though note that CIM objects fundamentally lack methods and require use of `Invoke-CimMethod`.)</sup>

Comment: Thank u, by the way WMI command does not work on "PowerShell (Core) v6+" and above right?

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki, indeed they are not part of PowerShell (Core) anymore - though in recent versions you can call them via the Windows Compatibility feature, which is best avoided, however; see the 2nd footnote I've added to the answer.

Comment: I'm doing my best to make it work on older systems as well. That's my only purpose. For this reason, I will add the feature of adding my features by comparing the ps version in my next coding. Thanks for this good information.

Comment: By the way, I think there is one problem, but I not sure, I cannot forward my pipeline output to the my function "@args" is it normal? `function Get-WmiObject { Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_bios" @args }; Get-WmiObject | select Manufacturer | Remove-WmiObject`, **Remove-WmiObject** not finding class in here, is it normal?

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki, extra effort is needed if you want to support pipeline input - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842481/45375).