# How can I prepend a timestamp to every PowerShell output line?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make PowerShell automatically prepend a timestamp to every line subsequent to invoking my custom ShowTimeStamps function. The function attempts to redirect output thru a filter that prepends the timestamp.

```
function ShowTimeStamps {
    $originalOutput = $host.UI.RawUI.WriteLine
    $host.UI.RawUI.WriteLine = {
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"
        Write-Host "$timestamp $_"
    }
}
```

The above function is accepted by Powershell, but cannot be successfully invoked.
It produces the error:

```
The property 'WriteLine' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:3 char:5
+     $host.UI.RawUI.WriteLine = {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Comment: seems like you're trying to override the builtin function `prompt`. assigning a value to `WriteLine` (a method) is not valid in this case

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to prefix every *output* line with a timestamp ([Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77289427/45375) shows you how add a timestamp to the *prompt* line).

While overriding the [`Out-Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default) cmdlet in regular user code is normally to be avoided, here you can use a *proxy function* that combines `Out-String -Stream` with `Out-Host` to do what you want:

```bash
function Out-Default {

  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject
  )
  
  begin {

    $scriptCmd = { 
       Out-String -Stream | 
         ForEach-Object { 
           (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff ') + $_ | Out-Host 
         } 
    }

    $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
    $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
  }
  
  process {
    $steppablePipeline.Process($InputObject)
  }
  
  end {
    $steppablePipeline.End()
  }
  
}
```

- Once this function is defined (and in scope), every line in *to-host* output will be prefixed with a timestamp; e.g.:

  ```bash
   PS> Get-Date
   2023-10-13 13:31:57.2870780
   2023-10-13 13:31:57.2872810 Friday, October 13, 2023 1:31:57 PM
   2023-10-13 13:31:57.2873870
  ```
- Captured or redirected output will *not* be affected (however, on trying to *display* captured / redirected output, timestamps will again surface).

  - However, the timestamps *are* captured in *session transcripts* created with [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript).
- To revert to the default display behavior, simply remove the function:

  ```bash
   Remove-Item Function:Out-Default
  ```
- For more information about *proxy functions*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you're looking for, it seems you may be looking to override your built-in [`prompt` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.3). Overriding it to display the date in your desired format is quite easy, as an example:

```bash
function prompt {
    "PS $($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation) - $([datetime]::Now.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff'))$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}
```

Then your prompt would show the current location followed by a hyphen followed by the date and time in your desired format:

```bash
PS C:\Users\user - 2023-10-13 13:39:58.1856995>
```

This is of course as customizable as you want.